# CPQ Quote Template - include current date in generated quote

Tags: cpq, quote, quote-template

I was curious if there is a way to get the current date in the generated quote? I currently have the 'Date:' field referencing the 'CreatedDate' formula field that just calls 'CreatedDate', however, I would like to have today's date entered somehow without having to create a new field.

I was hoping to be able to do this via JavaScript on the CPQ Quote Template. Is there a way to reference a system standard DATE() or TODAY() script for that field?

Comment: Is this CPQ quote template? Please edit your question to clarify

Comment: @identigral sorry about that....made the edits.  Yes, it's for CPQ Quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no trivial solution for inserting dynamic content such as current date - you have to use a field. Here's an example that deals with date format rather than dates but it's the same idea: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323806/cpq-quote-template-change-date-format-on-the-pdf-quote

Comment: @identigral yep, that is what I was using and referencing the existing 'CreatedDate' field.  Ok, that's what I thought.  Thank you for the help.